# Autofit VBA excel extract

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating an extract in excel. I'm pulling data from SQL Server - then writing it to excel. At first I create headers by specifying the row,  see below....

```vb
With xlSheetInfo
.Cells(5, 1).ColumnWidth = 50
.Cells(5, 1).Value = "School"
.Cells(5, 2).ColumnWidth = 25
.Cells(5, 2).Value = "Name"
.Cells(5, 3).Value = "Q1"
.Cells(5, 4).Value = "Comments"
end with
```

then i write the data, using the recordset

```vb
While Not g_RS3.EOF
For i = xlCol To rCount
    Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS3("Location")
    Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Font.Bold = True
    xlCol = xlCol + 1
    Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS3("LastName") & " ," & g_RS3("FirstName")
    xlCol = xlCol + 1
    Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS3("Q01")
    xlCol = xlCol + 1
    Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS3("Comments")
next i
wend
```

The problem I come across is the "Comments" as this field can have up to 500 characters. Since this is the last column in my extract I'd like it to be AUTOFIT. Actually because there is alot of records, I'd like for it to autofit or autosize according to the length of the longest comment. I'm not sure where I should include this to make it autofit. How would I fix this?

Comment: Try with `Range.AutoFit` : xlSheetInfo.Columns(4).AutoFit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `AutoFit` method:

```
Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS3("Comments")
Cells(xlRow, xlCol).EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: Thanks @Macroman -- I have another question, i'm not sure if you'd be ableto help me here or if should ask another question. But in my comments section, there are cases, where users enter line breaks, and at time they will enter one comment, 5 spaces and another comment for the same record(Why? No clue), however, is there a way to get rid of the spaces and have the text appear without any spaces in between

Comment: Needs to be another question I'm afraid.